# How to call response values to next request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

If the response like

```
<Hawrwid>1234<\Hawrwid> <Hawrwid>1235<\Hawrwid>
<Hawrwid>1236<\Hawrwid>
```

and so on.
How to pass same values in next post request? please suggest me possible way

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to pass the whole response to the next request - go for [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) with empty left and right boundaries - it will save the full response into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. If you need to pass individual parts of the response, like these  `1234`, `1235` and `1236` - you can fetch them using [XPath2 Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-xpath2-extractor-how-to-achieve-better-correlations)
3. For anything more complex like transform the response into a different structure - go for [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor), [GPath](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath) and [MarkupBuilder](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_markupbuilder)

Answer (score 0):

Use [XPath2 Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-xpath2-extractor-how-to-achieve-better-correlations) and `//Hawrwid[1], //Hawrwid[2], //Hawrwid[3]` Xpath queries. Name the variables in extractor, then use them like this `'${variable_name}'` in next requests.